# N-Quarters in a circle, remove either one each turn, or two tangent coins each turn. Whoever takes the last quarter loses.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

There are N quarters arranged in a circle so that each quarter is tangent to the two adjacent quarters. At each turn, a player removes either one quarter anywhere in the circle or two quarters that are tangent to each other. The player who takes the last quarter loses.

I'm trying to figure out for what values of 'n' is makes going 1st better and what value of 'n' makes going second better.

For one coin, obviously going second is a win.
For two coins, going first is a win.
For three coins, going first is a win.
For four coins, going second is a win.
For five coins, going first is a win.

I don't see a pattern out of these. This problem comes from a Boston University Number Theory camp.

All help appreciated.

For 6 coins, going first is a win.

Comment: the one or two condition suggests a second order Fibonacci recurrence, and your five stated values match the Fibonacci numbers reduced mod 2, so maybe that is a direction to try

Comment: You're right about the Fibonacci numbers mod 2. I'll keep going and see if this still works

Comment: Once the first one or two quarters has been removed, the game becomes [kayles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayles) with misere play.  I found a [web page](https://miseregames.wordpress.com/2003/09/21/the-discovery-of-the-solution-to-misere-kayles/) discussing the solution, but I haven't read it.

Comment: Thank you so much @saulspatz. I'll read them right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first move, this game is isomorphic to a game of misère Kayles. Kayles is played with a line of quarters instead of a circle, and the legal moves are removing any quarter or any pair of adjacent quarters. The word "misère" means that the player who removes the last quarter loses, while in "normal" Kayles, the player who takes the last quarter wins.

Normal play Kayles is quite simple; the first player wins for a row of quarters with any nonzero length, by dividing the row in half and using a mirror strategy. Misère Kayles was solved by Seifert and Conway (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01253778). The solution is described in section $5$ of *Daisies, Kayles, and the Sibert-Conway decomposition in misère octal games* (https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(92)90343-E). The misère play outcome is usually equal to the normal play outcome, and that paper describes the full list of exceptional positions where the misère outcome is opposite the normal outcome. In particular, the only $n$ for which a row of $n$ is a second player win in misère Kayles are the following:
$$
1,4,9,12,20
$$
Therefore, for the misère game of $n$ quarters in a circle, the game is always a second player win, unless the first player can produce a row with one of the exceptional lengths above, which which is possible iff it exceeds those numbers by $1$ or $2$. That is, the only $n$ for which the first player wins with $n$ quarters in a circle are:
$$
2,3,\; 5,6,\; 10,11,\;13,14,\; 21,22
$$
This agrees with what you have found so far.

However, the winning strategy for misere Kayles is not simple, and certainly not something you would expect an undergraduate to be able to find over the course of a summer.

Comment: I'm 15 in high school, but your point remains. I started this problem yesterday and haven't made much progress.

Comment: Thanks for your tremendous help

Comment: @Knocker379 I can see two possibilities. (1) They did not expect you to solve this problem, and it was an exercise to see how many values of $n$ you could solve it for, what patterns you could find, etc. (2) The organizers mistakenly gave you the "last coin loses" variant, which is quite hard, when they meant to give you the "last coin wins" variant which is a fun and easy puzzle.

Comment: I just talked to them and they apologized and said they meant to give the last coin wins variant. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Haha, I suspected that, thanks for confirming. Enjoy the rest of the camp! @Knocker379